# Where can I submit my undergraduate thesis?

Tags: publications

I am now a teacher. I am aiming to submit my undergraduate thesis to any journals or publications or conferences. Where can I submit it online?

Comment: How about starting with a journal relevant to your field? Seeing as you didn't tell us what that is it's impossible to help.

Comment: I would start with some of the journals you may have cited in your thesis. Regardless, it's worrying that you have to ask this website, rather than already have some inkling through your research, or asking some of your fellow researchers.

Answer (score 3):

An undergraduate thesis is not normally submitted online as a publication in a journal or a conference. You first need to find out if it is worthy of publication, meaning that it contributes to advancing the state of the art. If so, then you will have to present it or part of it in a style suitable for a journal/conference publication.